# How to install Amazon MP3 Downloader on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mp3, amazon-web-services

Looks like some dependencies are missing from Amazon MP3 Downloader. I Googled, but couldn't find a working solution (there are a few blog posts, but they are old).

What steps do I need to follow to install it correctly?

Comment: First step is to provide us with the exact error message.

Comment: Also the ubuntu Version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the Amazon downloader is always "behind the times" and frequently doesn't work on the most current version of a linux OS.

You might, instead, try [pymazon](http://code.google.com/p/pymazon/) which is why I've been using for downloading Amazon purchases.  It might be available in your package manager already (my Ubuntu machine isn't turned on at the moment or I'd test it for you; it is packaged in Fedora).

Comment: I followed the steps for pymazon, it throws a bunch of errors - dependency errors.  My machine is 64 bit, is it because of it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically need the Amazon MP3 Downloader? Otherwise, Banshee supports Amazon MP3 Downloads since [version 1.7.2](http://banshee.fm/download/archives/1.7.3/).

Answer (score 0):

The [current release of Amazon MP3 downloader for Ubuntu](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/dmusic/help/amd.html?forceos=LINUX) supports Ubuntu 9.10.  For newer versions, here are complete instructions:

- [Installing Amazon’s MP3 Downloader on Ubuntu 10.04 and Debian Squeeze](http://www.hilltopyodeler.com/blog/?p=294)
- [Installing Amazon MP3 Downloader on Ubuntu 10.10](http://martinwebster.eu/2010/10/16/installing-amazon-mp3-downloader-on-ubuntu-10-10/)

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon MP3 package requires a fairy old set of audio packages to install. These packages are no longer in the normal repositories, so you can download the required packages either from the Ubuntu Hardy Heron repository at [packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/). I've made an archive on dropbox, [here's the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s5vjnt8zimf0ldz/amazonmp3.tar.xz) but you don't have to trust me and can get them yourself through searching.

For reference, the packages are

> libboost-date-time1.34.1
>
> libboost-filesystem1.34.1
>
> libboost-iostreams1.34.1
>
> libboost-regex1.34.1
>
> libboost-signals1.34.1
>
> liboost-thread1.34.1
>
> libicu38